# Unable to load static resources with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, staticresource

Can you please help me with an issue I have with loading static resources? I tried the official Spring Security tutorial as well as trying to find up-to-date information on the Internet. Nothing seems to work. I can't access static resources from any folder in my Demo Spring App.

Here's a link to the DemoApp repo - https://github.com/StanislavStanev/SpringMVCDemoApp

In the main folder of the Repo is a presentation that I used as a guide, on how to configure the damn thing - (file name)10. Java-MVC-Frameworks-Filters-and-User-Authentication

Here's links, where I tried to find a solution to my problem:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-requestmatcher

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-static-resources

[Spring Security Thymleaf static resources don't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809561/spring-security-thymleaf-static-resources-dont-load)

[Serving static web resources in Spring Boot & Spring Security application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916894/serving-static-web-resources-in-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

https://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll

This is a screenshot of the Network tab in my browser, saying that I'm able to find a resources, but need to be redirected, etc. I tried putting the same resource in different folders, toying with different configurations on different classes.

[browser-network-tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Qt3.png)

If you need more information, please let me know. I really need to figure this out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please avoid posting links to repositories that include your entire project and try to include all the relevant code in your post.

Comment: Thank you, Nikos. This makes perfect sense and I realize, that my post isn't perfect. However, this is a test project. There's nothing sensitive there. What I really hope for, is that someone who has built Spring Security will see this and tell me, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I hope someone can help too! Personally I don't know anything about it, I just thought, seeing that you're new here, I could warn you in case no one replies here, that you shouldn't feel disheartened. Just edit your question and try again!

Comment: Try changing css reference in your html file as - <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/public/style.css}">

Comment: Thank you, to all who took of their time to look at my question. I solved it, by re-applying the steps in the manual I posted above. For some reason, this time it worked. It finds css and js files from the initial resources folder, under /css and /js.